# Is it possible to send facebook game requests in Flutter?

Tags: android, facebook, flutter

Looking at Facebook documents i can see that its possible to send game requests in both Android and IOS.

I am currently using the flutter_facebook_login to log users in.

What i am looking for is a way to let the logged users invite their friends to the game.

So, is it possible to invite Facebook friends to a Flutter app using http or a Flutter sdk? or do i have to implement it separately using the native libraries for both Android and IOS?